# How to navigate from nested Fragment to parent fragment using Jetpack Navigation?

Tags: android, android-jetpack, android-navigation, android-architecture-navigation

I have main navigation:
SplashFragment -> RegistrationFragment -> RootFragment

```
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/splashFragment"
    android:name="com.low6.low6.features.splash.SplashFragment"
    android:label="Splash"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_splash" >
    <action
        android:id="@+id/action_next"
        app:clearTask="true"
        app:destination="@id/registrationFragment" />
</fragment>

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/registrationFragment"
    android:name="com.low6.low6.features.registration.RegistrationFragment"
    android:label="Register">
    <action
        android:id="@+id/action_next"
        app:clearTask="true"
        app:destination="@id/rootFragment" />
</fragment>

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/rootFragment"
    android:name="com.low6.low6.core.RootFragment"
    android:label="@string/home"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_root" />
```

And I have nested registration navigation:
RegistrationPersonalFragment -> RegistrationContactFragment -> RegistrationSecurityFragment

```
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/registrationPersonalFragment"
    android:name="com.low6.low6.features.registration.RegistrationPersonalFragment"
    android:label="Register">

    <action
        android:id="@+id/action_next"
        app:destination="@+id/registrationContactFragment" />
</fragment>

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/registrationContactFragment"
    android:name="com.low6.low6.features.registration.RegistrationContactFragment"
    android:label="Register">

    <action
        android:id="@+id/action_next"
        app:destination="@+id/registrationSecurityFragment" />
</fragment>

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/registrationSecurityFragment"
    android:name="com.low6.low6.features.registration.RegistrationSecurityFragment"
    android:label="Register">

    <action
        android:id="@+id/action_next"
        app:destination="@+id/rootFragment" />
</fragment>
```

How to redirect from the last nested RegistrationSecurityFragment to RootFragment using Jetpack Navigation component?

Currently

```
<action
    android:id="@+id/action_next"
    app:destination="@+id/rootFragment" />
```

And

```
   navigateTo(R.id.action_next)
```

Gives me

```
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: navigation destination com.xxx:id/rootFragment referenced from action com.xxx:id/action_next is unknown to this NavController
    at androidx.navigation.NavController.navigate(NavController.java:691)
    at androidx.navigation.NavController.navigate(NavController.java:648)
    at androidx.navigation.NavController.navigate(NavController.java:634)
    at com.xxx.core.BaseFragment.navigateTo(BaseFragment.kt:73)
    at com.xxx.core.BaseFragment.navigateTo$default(BaseFragment.kt:66)
    at com.xxx.features.registration.RegistrationSecurityFragment$epoxyController$1$$special$$inlined$button$lambda$1.onClick(RegistrationSecurityFragment.kt:106)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6597)
    at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:6574)
    at android.view.View.access$3100(View.java:778)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:25885)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you have more than one navigation graph, please make sure you're using the right navigation controller. Using Navigation.findNavController(view) in some cases you might need to get your root view to get the root's navigation. Hope, this'll help.

Comment: How to get root view?

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky you can pass your host's navController to your child fragment maybe?

Answer (score 8):

When you have **nested** NavControllers, `findNavController()` return only last. To get previous navControllers, you can traverse up using `parentFragment` property.

Extensions with this approach:

```
// find all nav controllers from closest to farest
fun Fragment.findAllNavControllers(): List<NavController> {
    val navControllers = mutableListOf<NavController>()
    var parent = parentFragment
    while (parent != null) {
        if (parent is NavHostFragment) {
            navControllers.add(parent.navController)
        }
        parent = parent.parentFragment
    }
    return navControllers
}

// find one nav controller by fragment id
fun Fragment.findNavControllerById(@IdRes id: Int): NavController {
    var parent = parentFragment
    while (parent != null) {
        if (parent is NavHostFragment && parent.id == id) {
            return parent.navController
        }
        parent = parent.parentFragment
    }
    throw RuntimeException("NavController with specified id not found")
}
```

And usage:

```
findAllNavControllers()[2]
findNavControllerById(R.id.navHostFragment)
```

Comment: The second extension function was what I needed. Thanks.

Comment: Second extension function works, but for some reason the actual id is different than the resource id

Answer (score 1):

In your code, you can pass the resource ID of the global action to the `navigate()` method for each UI element.

```
your_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
   @Override
   public void onClick(View view) {
       Navigation.findNavController(view).navigate(R.id.main_fragment);
   }
});
```

Comment: It doesn't work, I'm afraid `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: navigation destination com.xxx:id/rootFragment is unknown to this NavController`

Comment: I can confirm getting same error as @qbait in my app

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @Vladimir answer I came up with this solution

```
val mainNavView = requireActivity().findViewById<View>(R.id.mainNavFragment)
Navigation.findNavController(mainNavView).navigate(R.id.action_next)
```

Comment: What is `mainNavFragment`?

Comment: `mainNavFragment` is probably the `Fragment` which hosts the nested navigation. Looks like he's recovering the top most nav host fragment and using it's actions directly from the nested fragment.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this ;

in Child Fragment

```
// parentFragment = getParentFragment() for java
(parentFragment as MyParentFragment).myNavigationHandler(myArguments)
```

in Parent Fragment

```
fun myNavigationHandler(myArguments) {
    Navigation.findNavController(binding.root)
        .navigate(MyFragmentDirections.actionMyAction(myArguments))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
findNavController().navigate(HostFragmentDirections.actionHostToOtherFragment())
```

HostFragment is just an example, which should be the name of host of your nested fragment.
For everyone struggling with navigating to somewhere from your nested fragment, this works.

Answer (score 0):

There is already a way given by Navigation class. I have the same design you have. I am using below line to navigation to top fragment

```
Navigation.findNavController(requireActivity(),R.id.nav_host_fragment).navigate(R.id.homeFragment)
```

where `R.id.nav_host_fragment` is fragmentcontainerview id which is present in root activity like below

```
<androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
            android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment"
            android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:clipToPadding="false"
            app:defaultNavHost="true"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/bottomNav"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:navGraph="@navigation/nav_graph" />
```

**Don't forget to import the correct package**

```
import androidx.navigation.Navigation
```

**Note :** The id of root fragment container and child fragment container must be different. So it does not clash and find the correct NavController.